# HMS: Not able to enable account kit from manage API in AGC Console

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect, huawei-account

I'm new to Huawei Account Kit Integration, not able to enable account kit from manage API in AGC Console.

I'm Following below link for integration-

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/harmonyos-java-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001148191776#section12164516163

can any one help me Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account kit API is enabled by default for Harmony OS applications, so you can continue to run and debug with account kit integration.
Please check below pointe:

1. Update HMS core to latest version
2. Check OAuth client ID in config.json.

Refer the below link 6th step to configure client id.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/harmonyos-java-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001148191776#section12164516163

*@kgsharathkumar* - For me, faced the same issue and got a solution.